# Cannot login to webservice, it doesn't seem to respond

Tags: android, json, web-services, http, post

So i got the address `www.biokod.net:8990/api`, authentication data  `jkowalski@test.pl:123456` and connection method should be post. When i try to connect to `www.biokod.net:8990/api` throught web browser it doesn't seem to respond but the person who sent me this data claims that it is working just fine. How can i connect to this server?

Comment: you should use postman and try to hit that api. and just conform that the authentication data is in which format, like is it in json format or form data.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, for some reason internet in my office was blocking this request. I tried it from my home pc and everything is working fine.